# Rearranging the word BASKETBALL

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've tried doing this question that I've listed below. I started and finished part a, but I am unsure if I have the correct answer. I am also unsure how to begin part b so if someone could help I would appreciate it! The question is written below. Thank you.

**Question:**

How many ways can you arrange the letters of the word BASKETBALL if:

a) the arrangement must begin with an S and end with a T?

b) all of the vowels must be kept together?

**Working For Part A:**

Since the arrangement must begin with an S and end with a T, we have 8 more letters remaining, so there should be $1\times8!\times1=40\ 320$ arrangements.

Comment: You need to account for the repeats of BB,LL,AA by dividing by 2!2!2!

Comment: For part b), consider tying all the vowels together into a single "letter" (of which there are 3 possibilities), and see what words you can make with these 8 "letters"

Answer (score 1):

> How many ways can the letters of the word BASKETBALL be arranged if the arrangement must begin with an S and end with a T?

Your answer would be correct if the letters in the word BASKETBALL were distinct.  However, they are not.

There are ten letters in the word BASKETBALL.  If we place an S in the first position and a T in the tenth position, we must fill the middle eight positions with two As, two Bs, two Ls, one E, and one K.  Choose two of the eight positions for the As, two of the remaining six positions for the Bs, and two of the remaining four positions for the Ls, and one of the remaining two positions for the E.  The K must be placed in the remaining open position.

> There are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to choose two of the eight positions for the As, $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose two of the remaining six positions for the Bs, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two of the remaining four positions for the Ls, $\binom{2}{1}$ ways to choose one of the remaining two positions for the E, and one way to place the K in the final open position.  Hence, there are $$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1} = \frac{8!}{2!6!} \cdot \frac{6!}{2!4!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{1!1!} = \frac{8!}{2!2!2!1!1!}$$ arrangements of the word BASKETBALL in which the arrangement must begin with an S and end with a T.  The factors in the denominator count the number of ways indistinguishable letters could be permuted among themselves without changing the arrangement.  For instance, we could switch the positions of the two As in a given arrangement without producing an arrangement distinguishable from that arrangement.  Notice that there are $2!$ ways of permuting the two As.

> How many ways can the letters of the word BASKETBALL be arranged if all the vowels must be kept together?

Let's give you a strategy to implement.

1. Place the three vowels in a box labeled V.
2. We have eight objects to arrange: two Bs, two Ls, one K, one S, one T, and one V.  Implement the method used in part (a) of the problem to arrange them.
3. Within the box labeled V, we have three objects to arrange: two As and one E.  Implement the method used in part (a) to arrange them.
4. Multiply the number of ways of arranging two Bs, two Ls, one K, one S, one T, and one V by the number of ways of arranging two As and one E within the box labeled V.